# OpenGL - Sampler2D array in GLSL 120?

Tags: arrays, macos, opengl

I'm working on a game engine, and I need to have an array of Sampler2Ds in my fragment shader to support multiple textures. On GLSL 130 and above it looks like this:

```
uniform sampler2D textures[32];
```

Sadly, my graphics card is just the default Intel with OpenGL 2.1, so it doesn't support Sampler2D arrays. How can I achieve this without creating 32 uniforms for each texture if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve it no matter what you do. Your "default Intel with OpenGL 2.1" does not allow you to access 32 textures in one shader stage. Period. You'll only get that on more recent hardware which supports OpenGL 4.x. So even on GLSL 1.30, that would probably fail.

The best you can hope for is support for [EXT_texture_array](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_array.txt), which would allow you to have `sampler2DArray` types. This would allow you to create `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT` texture types, which can have multiple array layers. You can access individual layers of the texture without any crossover.

Also, depending on what you're doing, texture atlases may be possible.

Comment: I highly support the texture atlas suggestion. Most things can be implemented with them and its very portable and fast. Caveats usually only come up when using too many mip map levels on the texture atlas, which is a manageable problem in most situations.

Comment: I found a way past this issue, I didn't know about it before, but changing OpenGL to a Core Profile solved the issue, and I could access 16 textures at a time.